# How to map the row data in ag grid to field of field obtained by API in json.?

Tags: angular, typescript

how to map to the values required?

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import "ag-grid-enterprise";
@Component({
  selector: 'app-lists',
  templateUrl: './lists.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./lists.component.css']
})
export class ListsComponent implements OnInit {

columnDefs = [
  {headerName: 'Funds #', field: 'portfolioId',filter:false,Sorting:false},
  {headerName: 'Short Name', field: 'portfolioName',filter:false,Sorting:false}  
];
ngOnInit(){
  this.myData= this.http.get('https://aswsfl29sit.fmrco.com:22933/CCService/resource/projectedcashdetails/3?offsetNumber=0&json=true');
  console.log(this.myData);
}
}`enter code here`
```

i want to display field of field of portfolio(portfolio->x->y) which i obtained in json format from an API. As this field has further parts ,there is nothing being display in ag grid.`enter code here`

Comment: Can I see how the data looks like?

Comment: "portfolioId":{"localAmt":0,"baseAmt":0,"usdAmt":0,"requestedAmount":0},"portfolioName":{"localAmt":0,"baseAmt":0,"usdAmt":0,"requestedAmount":0},"priorTradesAmt":{"localAmt":0,"baseAmt":0,"usdAmt":0,"requestedAmount":0},"ordTradesAmt":}

Comment: I am a bit confused there - `portfolioId`  and `portfolioName ` are both objects?

Comment: What are the values you need to display under the columns Funds # and Short Name

Answer (score 0):

With regards to your question and the sample data you've provided, first, this is what you should have on your lists.component.html:

```
<ag-grid-angular 
  class="ag-theme-balham-dark" 
  [rowData]="myData" 
  [columnDefs]="columnDefs" 
  (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)" 
   <!-- other ag-grid properties -->
 >
 </ag-grid-angular>
```

On your component.ts, I notice this glaring issue. While you have made the HTTP GET request, you did not return the values. You will need to `subscribe()` to it to return the observable values, so that the values can be used.

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import "ag-grid-enterprise";
@Component({
  selector: 'app-lists',
  templateUrl: './lists.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./lists.component.css']
})
export class ListsComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  columnDefs = [
    {headerName: 'Funds #', field: 'portfolioId',filter:false,Sorting:false},
    {headerName: 'Short Name', field: 'portfolioName',filter:false,Sorting:false}  
  ];

  ngOnInit() {
this.http.get('https://aswsfl29sit.fmrco.com:22933/CCService/resource/projectedcashdetails/3?offsetNumber=0&json=true').subscribe(res => {
    this.myData = res;
    console.log(this.myData);
    // do the rest to ensure that myData is a single level array of objects
  });
}
```